# Devise: Add User Details in different table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have two models User and Person

I want to stick with the default table for the user offered by Devise to include only email and password and add User details in Person

Here is my models

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord   
belongs_to :user 
end
```

User Model

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    has_one :person
    ...
 end
```

I also override RegistrationController.rb to look like this

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def sign_up_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end

end
```

and here is the view

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.fields_for :person do |p| %>
  <%= p.text_field :first_name %>
  <%= p.text_field :last_name %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

With the code it didn't work, and it didn't update the people column while registration

**How Can I get devise to add details in two models using the only one form offered by devise ? 
To add email and password in Users Table
and other details e.g. first_name in People Table**

Comment: What are you asking? This isn't really a question. If it doesn't work, then what happens right now when you try this code? Also `Person` should not contain `belongs_to :person`

Comment: Ok I am editing the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Nested-Models setup for simple_form

Add `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to `User` model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :person
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person
end
```

Update permit params in controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation,
      person_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name])
  end
end
```

Change `f.fields_for :person` to `f.simple_fields_for :person` in view.

Check https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models

Comment: I applied changes but text fields in the views had disappeared, I tried to edit UsersController to add @user.people.build in the new action but nothing happened

Comment: Maybe `@user.build_person unless @user.person` will work

Comment: @user.build_person solved the problem, It's working now. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set strong params inside your controller private method as per below:

```
def sign_up_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, person_attributes: [:person_model_attributes])
end
```

Inside your User model add below line:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :person
```